# Count with reduce

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have the current code (snippet) but I want to count the total of the answers

Example:

```
"2022-01-03": {
    "yes": 1,
    "no": 2,
    "total": 3
  }
```

```js
const array = [
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'no' },
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'no' },
  { date: '2022-01-04', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-04', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'no' },
]

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.date]) {
    acc[curr.date] = { yes: 0, no: 0 }
  }
  acc[curr.date][curr.answer]++;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Does your solution have to be a reduce method?

Comment: you need to use `array.forEach`  with  toplevel empty object not `array.reduce`.

Comment: @bogdanoff just no. Reduce is a good choice for grouping things.

Comment: @bogdanoff why is that *needed*?

Comment: @VLAZ neglect it, i messed few things while the reading question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `total` field and increment for every value:

```js
const array = [
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'no' },
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'no' },
  { date: '2022-01-04', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-04', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'no' },
]

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.date]) {
    acc[curr.date] = { yes: 0, no: 0, total: 0 }
  }
  acc[curr.date][curr.answer]++;
  acc[curr.date].total++;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a [getter field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for `total`, so it will be automatically calculated:

```js
const array = [
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'no' },
  { date: '2022-01-03', answer: 'no' },
  { date: '2022-01-04', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-04', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'yes' },
  { date: '2022-01-05', answer: 'no' },
]

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.date]) {
    acc[curr.date] = { 
      yes: 0, no: 0, 
      get total() { return this.yes + this.no; } 
    }
  }
  acc[curr.date][curr.answer]++;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't see any problem in your code, but I shortened one line and it became more optimized.

From:

```js
const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.date]) {
    acc[curr.date] = { yes: 0, no: 0 }
  }
  acc[curr.date][curr.answer]++;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

to

```js
const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.date] ||= { yes: 0, no: 0, total: 0 };
  acc[curr.date][curr.answer]++;
  acc[curr.date][total]++
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).